# How to make emission object transparent in EEVEE?

Tags: materials, shaders, eevee-render-engine, transparency, emission

I would like to make this emission material I made transparent in order to make it look like an energy field and be able to see the door behind it:

[image]

Tried the alpha blend option in EEVEE but it did not work

[image]

And idea how I can do that?

Comment: do you have a picture of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I added a picture.  I want the blue emission to be transparent in order to look like an energy shield protecting the door behind it.  I want the door to be seen through the blue light.

Comment: you need to mix Emission and Transparent in a Mix Shader, maybe plug a Noise Texture into the factor of the Mix Shader (and Texture Coordinate > Mapping node before the Noise), it would be a basic way to do it, and you can animate the energy effect with the Mapping parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use something like this. make sure to change your blend mode.

[image: TransEmit]

For an energy shield effect, you can try adding a wave texture (vertical lines) with a bit of distortion to make it look "energized", and mixing it with a gradient texture to make the field "weaker" in the middle.

[image: Energ]

Comment: what is the multiply not called? I cannot find it. Thanks very much.  Found it.

Comment: It's a MixRGB node set to "multiply" instead of "mix"

Answer (score 1):

A reference image would be good to start. Have a look at the render[image: reference image]. Is it what you are asking for. And yes it can be done using emission and glass shader with some noise as a factor.[image: Node Setup]